# React native application being killed by ios 13 due to exceeding limit of 80% cpu over 60 seconds

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using below versions of react and react-native and facing crashing issues on ios 13, My app is being killed by ios after putting the app in background. I have attached crash logs below as i am unable to find out the reason behind the process being killed.
Could anybody help me understand the problem?

"react": "16.8.6"
"react-native": "0.60.5"
Crash log:[Crash log file](https://www.writeurl.com/text/ixzwwwnkyaw5ioegnzv1/u7v00uinh873wcm91pr0)

Comment: Have you implement any app state change listeners in you app

Comment: Yes i have implemented that.

Comment: Could you add few lines of it here

Comment: AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);

 private handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState: string) => {
    
    if (this.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      // Some logic
    } else if (this.appState.match('active') && nextAppState.match(/inactive|background/)) {
      // Some logic
    }
    this.appState = nextAppState;
    
  }

Comment: Did you try by removing the listener

Comment: I havn't tried that, I will  try it out.

Comment: I think there might be some issues with your listener so please add few debug point and check from where is happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207148/discussion-between-gagan-and-el173).

Comment: I had the same problem when using react-native-camera. I had to stop react-native-camera when in background with an AppState listener to reduce the number of errors.